# Augmented reality through the use of an external camera. Android Development

Tags: android, augmented-reality, android-camera-intent, ip-camera

So I have been working in a project of my own and I encountered the biggest road block when I realized that it was apparently very difficult to use in SDK such as Vuforia, Metaio, Wikitube, DroidAr and NyArtToolKit a external camera communicating through Wi-Fi to a android device.

Now, I have two android devices smoothly connected through wi-fi. I can see the camera view from one device in the other device. I would like to use that view in the receiving android device in order to "create" the augmented reality experience. Because there is not a widely used of such a technique, those big AR SDK have not worked for me. I cannot pay for them either.

Do anyone know what can I do or if you can point me to a tutorial that deals with this issue? I obtained the bitmap from the server device and send everything through IP/UDP packages to the other devices.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you sort out your problem of using remote camera with AR? I have been looking around the AR SDKs But nothing happening. :(

Comment: Nop, I contacted different AR SDK providers and none of them would allow this capability. They were working on that feature or they had it in their to-do list but at the time, it was not possible. Sorry mate